# Symfony mapping subform

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I created a form of the customer.

**CustomerType**

```
$builder
    ->add('username', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'customer.form.email',
    ))
    ->add('plainPassword', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'customer.form.password',
    ))
    ->add('address', new AddressType)
;
```

To enter an address I want to use a second form.

**AddressType**

The class contains a form field.
By default: 'data_class' => 'Customer Bundle\Entity\Address'

**Result after submitting the form**

```
Customer:
#id: 0
#username: 'test'
...
#address: ArrayCollection
```

I need:

```
Customer:
#id: 0
#username: 'test'
...
#address: Address
```

There is a simple way to this solution?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853709/embed-one-form-into-another-symfony2 ?

Comment: please provide code for your customer entity and addresstype. .. It should noot be collectio unless you have it mapped on entity as collection (eg many-to-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
->add('address', $this->addressType, array(
    'data_class' => 'CustomerBundle\Entity\Address',
))
```

**data_class** must be set in the Customer Type